# Parsing JSON using Jackson: Can we have optional variables in a POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO with the following variables.

```
private Long poId;
private String nodeName;
private String fingerPrint;
private String hardwareResourceName;
private String sequenceNumber;
private String importedOn;
private String importedBy;
private String generated;
private String installedOn;
private String currentLicense;
private String productType;
```

Which is used to parse details about license files? 
When we make a call to certain rest endpoints, we get the following JSON response.

```
[{"nodeName":"LTE02ERBS00042","fingerprint":"LTE02ERBS00042_fp","hardwareResourceName":"ELSN","generatedOn":"1251359414000","installedOn":"","currentLicense":"false","sequenceNumber":9000,"importedOn":"1531929161227","poId":281475302769484,"filePath":"/home/smrs/smrsroot/licence/LTE02ERBS00042_fp/LTE02ERBS00042_fp_151008_060941.xml","importBy":"agatAdm7160","neType":"ERBS","platformType":"CPP"}
```

As you can see from the JSON, there are mismatches from what is returned in the response to the POJO e.g.: `from pojo: fingerPrint` `from JSON: fingerprint`. Also the JSON has extra fields which are not in the POJO. The POJO is used in other area's, so I do not want to change the existing functionality. I would like to add extra fields to accommodate the change in the data being returned, without having to create a separate POJO.

Is there a way with annotations that I can set a variable in the POJO to be optional or not always needed? So in cases where we get a JSON response with all the variables great, but if the response only has certain data, it will work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jackson has various features for dealing with this e.g. `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` can be switched off to allow for unknown properties in JSON that don't exist in POJO:

```
new ObjectMapper()
    .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
```

Take a look at [Jackson wiki](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki) which lists available features:

- [Mapper Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features)
- [Deserialization Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features)
- [Serialization Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features)

Answer (score 3):

I can think about two approaches and they are not mutually exclusive.

> Is there a way with annotations that I can set a variable in the POJO to be optional or not always needed?

You could store non-mapped properties in a `Map<String, Object>`:

```java
private Map<String, Object> otherProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

And then use a method annotated with [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html):

```java
@JsonAnySetter
public void setOtherProperty(String key, Object value) {
    otherProperties.put(key, value);
}
```

If you need to perform serialization of such properties, use a method annotated with [`@JsonAnyGetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnyGetter.html):

```java
@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, String> getOtherProperties() {
    return otherProperties;
}
```

> I would like to add extra fields to accommodate the change in the data being returned, without having to create a separate POJO.

If you know possible variations of the property names, you can use [`@JsonAlias`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAlias.html), which was introduced in Jackson 2.9:

```java
@JsonAlias({ "fingerprint", "fingerPrint" })
private String fingerprint;
```